# Yii2: How can I place something into a Breadcrumbs widget?

Tags: php, html, css, widget, yii2

I find the [Breadcrumbs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-breadcrumbs.html) widget quite useful. However, on the right side within the widget there is enough space for something else. If I'd like to put a link ('a' tag, but could be actually any other small thing) right aligned into the Breadcrumbs, how could I do that? What is a simple and proper solution? Should I extend the class, develop my own, use [begin](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html#begin%28%29-detail) and [end](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html#end%28%29-detail) of the widget somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs` you see that there is a third parameter in the breadcrumbs items

*From the Yii2 file*

```
   [
       'label' => 'Post Category',
       'url' => ['post-category/view', 'id' => 10],
       'template' => "<li><b>{link}</b></li>\n", // template for this link only
   ],
```

So by adding something like this in your main layout file

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = [
    'label' => 'Your Label', 
    'url' => ['controller/action'], 
    'template' => "<li style="float: right;">{link}</li>\n"
];
```

you will get a link at the right side. This link will come with a `/` prefixed, but you can bind it to a .class instead and configure it the way you want.

```
'template' => "<li class=\"yourClass\">{link}</li>\n"
```

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: Is there any way to customize the generated ul's class?